# Regex to find text between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Man, I'm confused. I've been looking at a million questions like these, but none of the answers work even if I simplify.

I want to capture text between `$[` and `]`.

Why doesn't `\$\[.*\]` work? Even if I follow guides for square brackets only it doesn't work.

[Jsfiddle to show that it doesn't work.](https://jsfiddle.net/ny1d2ob4/)

```
const content = "[Hey] (Ho) [f(1)]"
const example1 = '\[.*\]'
const example2 = '\[(.*?)\]'
const regex1 = new RegExp(example1, "g")
const regex2 = new RegExp(example2, "g")
const newText1 = content.replace(regex1, "EXAMPLE1")
const newText2 = content.replace(regex2, "EXAMPLE2")
console.log(newText1) //Prints [Hey] (Ho) [f(1)]
console.log(newText2) //Prints [Hey] EXAMPLE2HoEXAMPLE2 [fEXAMPLE21EXAMPLE2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the following regex to obtain multiple matches in your input string:

```
\$\[(.*?)\]
```

Note carefully that the capture group is `(.*?)`.  The question mark makes the match *non* greedy, meaning it will stop after hitting the nearest closing bracket.

```
var string = "stuff $[stuff] hello world $[123] blah [abc] $[def] blah";

var regex = new RegExp(/\$\[(.*?)\]/g);
var myArray;

while ((myArray = regex.exec(string)) != null) {
    alert(myArray[1])
}
```

If you had used the untempered `(.*)` as the capture group, there would have been only a single match starting from the first opening bracket and ending with the last closing bracket; clearly not what you intended.

**Demo here:**

## JSFiddle

Comment: There's a bug with this that it doesn't print out the correct string when it finds two brackets at the end. So `$[[hey]]` becomes `[hey`. Any idea to fix this behavior?

Comment: @Yeats If you have nested brackets then you should be using a parser.  There is no "bug" in this regex.

Comment: Looks pretty buggy to me.

Answer (score 0):

use with sub string  :`/\$\[(.*)\]/`  .And apply with `exec`

**[Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/e7r6RR/1)**

```js
var res=/\$\[(.*)\]/g.exec("$[and]");
console.log(res)
console.log(res[1])
```